# Question about Coulomb's Law and attraction of charges in uneven field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am trying to find the formula using Coulomb's Law for below drawing where instead of having two charges in the same charged field, the field strength is different between the two. I understand Coulomb's law as

$$F = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q_1 q_2}{d^2} $$

is there some way to correct for the additional uneven or additional attraction based on the field strength? I tried to make a drawing to show what I mean. Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture I'm just going to assume that the problem takes place in the plane. Moreover, it looks like potential is linearly increasing with horizontal distance $x$, so its derivative is constant. So we can write the external potential from

$$
\frac{\partial V(x,y)}{\partial x} = V_0 \implies V(x,y) = V_0 x. 
$$

where I have ignored the arbitrary constant of integration.

---

Your total potential at a given point $(x,y)$ should then be

$$
V(x,y) = V_{1} + V_{2} + V_0x 
$$

where $V_i = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}}$. You can now easily calculate the force on $q_1, q_2$.

Comment: Don't be a freeloader now. If it helped you either upvote or accept the answer if it answered your question